# Return to a previous acitivity without lose data

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, flags, start-activity

I have two activitys. Activity A e Activity B.

I have editText's with data inside Activity A. I pass to activity B.

But when i try to pass activity B to A, activity A restart and I lose the data in edittext. How I can pass of B to A with data inside A?

Here is my code in activity B. But doesn't work

```
       Intent afectarQuotaSocios = new Intent(B.this,A.class);
    afectarQuotaSocios.putExtra("ArrayListIdSocios",al);
    afectarQuotaSocios.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(afectarQuotaSocios);
```

Any ideas?
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use

```
startActivityForResult(Intent intent, int requestCode);
```

to start a subactivity. Like in case of yours, its B.

To Return result from an activity to its super activity, call

`setResult();` method

and get returned result in superactivity, in callback method, `onActivityResult()`

Comment: Hello jeet. Thanks for your reply. And if need to return to activity B and I need that the listview inside stay without changes? Your solution works fine thanks. But I need this to the A and B. How i can do this?

Comment: Write Code which you want to remain constant in onCreate method, and which you want to update on return from activity in onStart or onRestart method.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the [startActivityForResult](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29) method

Then on your B Activity you can pass your result :

```
resultIntent = new Intent(null);
resultIntent.putExtra(YOUR_CONSTANT_TEXT_IDENTIFIER, textValue);
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, resultIntent);
finish();
```

And you get the value on your A Activity on the [onActivityResult](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onActivityResult%28int,%20int,%20android.content.Intent%29) method

Answer (score 0):

You are starting a new Activity, which will call the started Activity's `onCreate` method, and start over again. What you want to do in order to keep the same state, is to call `finish()` from your Activity B.

Take a look at [`startActivityForResult`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29) in order to get this behavior that you're seeking.

Comment: But in same time I need to pass data (arrayList al) from activity B to activity A, and to do this I need intent.....

Answer (score 0):

In the Manifest file simply add this Tag to the Activity A `android:launchMode="singleInstance"` the onCreate won't be called for the Activity A and thus your data wouldn't be refreshed.

Comment: Your `OnCreate()` is called once(when app. starts) and then your `NewIntent()` method is called for rest of your code, where you can reload your Data.

Answer (score 0):

you create a new intent object,pass it back through the setResult(…) method call.
After that the finish() method is called to give the control back to the parent activity.

```
 Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
  returnIntent.putExtra("SELECTVALUE",book);
  setResult(RESULT_OK,returnIntent);        
  finish();
...
```

then you Back to your previous activity .

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
  {
  switch(requestCode) {
  case BOOK_SELECT: 
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            String name = data.getStringExtra("SELECTVALUE");
             System.out.println("Name"+name);
            }
```

}
}